# Hot Reload Breaks When Removing Bootstrap From Blazor Wasm Project

Tags: blazor-webassembly

Started with the Blazor Wasm starter template.  I've removed all the references to bootstrap from the project.  Now, hot reload only works on changes to the index.html file.  Seems like something is erroring out after that file in the blazor backend processing pipeline, which causes hot reload to stop working.  I can make changes down stream to the MainLayout.razor file or the Index.razor file and hot reload doesn't trigger.  But if i stop debugging and start again, those changes are loaded fine, just no hot reload.

I've spent hours bringing back bootstrap one reference at a time until my original project is back to the starter project.  Still hot reload does not work.  The Blazor.Client project is now identical to a new fresh blazor wasm project.  Hot load works on the new fresh project, yet still doesn't on the old project.  I've cleaned and rebuilt.  I've cleared the browser cache.

What could i be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Had to reboot Visual Studio 2022.  Hot reload now works.